# waitForKeyElements used with .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this script which works on a site, but I wanted to modify it for another use. Is it possible to use the `waitForKeyElements` function to look for text on a page (not text in a link)?

Here is the `div`:

```
<div id="action_pane" style="text-align: center;">You have run out of turns
```

Once that text "You have run out of turns." appears, I want the click function to click on a link that contains text which is different from the text found in `$action_pane`.  I cannot use this, as this text appears only when out of turns. I want to trigger a click on the link containing text "Start Again". This link is always there so I'm trying to work around it, or I would just use the working script.

Here is the working script that I want to modify:

```
function clickit (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}

waitForKeyElements (
    "a:contains('Restart')",
    clickit
);
```

This is my version that does not work:

```
function clickit () {
    $("a:contains('Start Again')").click();
}

waitForKeyElements (
    "a:contains('You have run out of turns.')",
    clickit
);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include the element which has the 'Start Again' text. Your code is looking for an `a` element which contains "Start Again", so if that's not the right element type it could be why that's failing.

Comment: i did this which works but the interval at which the text "You have run out of turns" is not exact so there is a delay as i set the interval higher than anticipated //setInterval(function(){
  $("a:contains('Start Again')").click();
}, 150000);

Comment: Actually, I think I mis-read what element you were trying to look at, please see my answer. But I agree with @thedeeno's suggestion that storing state in a variable rather than watching for text elements to change would make more sense for a game.

Answer (score 1):

Using the innerHTML of a DOM element is not the best way to store your system state. If I were you I'd take another approach entirely.

In your game, when you're out of turns you want to display the text "You have run out of turns" AND start again. So articulate that directly (instead of indirectly).

```
function takeTurn() {
  turnsLeft -= 1;
  if (turnsLeft <= 0) {
    showGameOverMessage();
    startAgain();
  }
}
```

That will make your code much easier to follow.

`startAgain` can be fired on a user click OR just called from your application logic. Make the operation the first-class citizen, not the user-interaction or side effects.

Comment: it is not my site rather a script i am trying to construct, what i am asking the script to do is click the link containing the text start again when the selector text on the web page displays you are out of turns using waitforkeyelements, not sure if its possible

Answer (score 0):

You have the following lines in your code:

```
waitForKeyElements (
    "a:contains('You have run out of turns.')",
    clickit
);
```

But earlier you said the element you're watching is:

```
<div id="action_pane" style="text-align: center;">You have run out of turns
```

This is a `div`, not an `a` element. So your selector should be changed to `div:contains('You  have run out of turns')`.

Comment: i tried that when the text appears it does not click Start Again, what i am asking the script to do is click the link containing the text start again when the selector text on the web page displays you are out of turns using waitforkeyelements

Comment: Which part of the script is not working? Is the selector for "Start Again" getting the right element?  Does the click function work?

Comment: i dont know, i dont think its the $("a:contains('Start Again')").click(); as it works wrapping it with set interval, is the version that i stated does not work above valid or possible? it has to be the other condition im using to trigger that using waitforkeyelements

Comment: So the selector for "You have run out of turns" is not working? One way to verify is by changing the 'clickit' function to something like an alert just to see if it's even triggered.

Comment: must be that, i changed to an alert and nothing happen, its the condition on which i want the click function to trigger using waitforkeyelements that seems to be the problem

Comment: Ok, unless there's something else you haven't mentioned I'm not sure what the issue is. Does the text in your selector match the text you're looking for exactly? Here's a quick example, perhaps that will help: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MayLGM